# mysql count quantity column and return position with row

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table:

```
ID int
category int
quantity int
timestamp timestamp
```

I want to SELECT id="id#" and return a 'position' which is the sum of quantity for each row that has an earlier timestamp in the same category.

Thanks for your pointers!

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly, but have you considered a `SELECT * FROM table where category='something' AND timestamp < some_timestamp`, and then doing the sum with PHP and selecting the sum value like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 'sum_result'` ?

Comment: I was looking to do it all in the DB, through only providing the ID

Comment: Try not to name columns with reserved words (ex: "timestamp timestamp").

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 I guess that was just for example purpose, but yeah, that's a good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sum(quantity) FROM TABLE WHERE category='...' AND timestamp < some_timestamp
```

If you want to select by id:

```
SELECT sum(quantity) FROM mytable
WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM mytable WHERE id=some_id)
AND timestamp <= some_timestamp
```

### UPDATE

To use the timestamp from the row itself, you could do something like:

```
SELECT sum(quantity) FROM mytable
WHERE category IN (SELECT category FROM mytable WHERE id=some_id)
AND timestamp <= (SELECT timestamp FROM mytable WHERE id=some_id)
```

..or use a self-join as in the Adam's answer (maybe it wasn't an overkill, after all.. :))

### UPDATE - Alternate solution

This seems to work fine too..

```
SELECT t1.id, sum(t2.quantity), t1.timestamp, t1.category
FROM mytable t1 INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.category=t2.category
WHERE t1.id=some_id_here AND t2.timestamp <= t1.timestamp;
```

### UPDATE

Changed `<` into `<=`, else the quantity for the selected item will not be counted!

Comment: This looks great, though how could I specify some_timestamp of the row through the id specified?

Comment: adding subquery instead of some_timestamp: (SELECT timestamp FROM table WHERE ID=some_id)

Answer (score 0):

You could join your table again with a subquery filtering on your criteria of same category and lesser timestamp.

Here's an example (this was done is sqlite, but it should work in mysql):

```
select
    ID,
    sum(foo2.quantity)
from
    foo
    left join (
        select category, quantity, timestamp from foo
    ) as foo2 on (
        foo.category = foo2.category
        and foo.timestamp > foo2.timestamp
    )
group by
    foo.ID
```

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
ID|category|quantity|timestamp
1 |foo     |2       |2011-01-01
2 |foo     |1       |2011-01-02
3 |foo     |4       |2011-01-03
4 |bar     |4       |2011-01-03
```

You'll get a result like this:

```
ID|sum(foo2.quantity)
1 |null
2 |2
3 |3
4 |null
```

Note: the nulls are because there is no data for those categories prior to the given record.

Note 2: Not sure how performant this will be, but it should get you the data you are looking for.

**Update**

After re-reading your question, this looks to be a bit overkill... I didn't realize you were passing the id in, either way you could still use this and add a `where id = "$id"` to restrict it to the id are looking at... hope this helps.

Comment: This is cool, but I think this is much more than what he asked :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this should do the trick.

```
$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID='$id'");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($r);
$cat = $r['category'];
$time = $r['timestamp'];
$r = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM table WHERE category='$cat' AND timestamp <= '$time'");
```

The first 4 lines retrieve your original id and find the category id and timestamp. Then we run a new query to get all the items in the category older than our id. Because we use <= for the timestamp, it will include our selected id's quantity. If we want to exclude our id's quantity, we would use just <

EDIT: Reading some of the other answers, you could use SUM and skip the while loop... you learn something new every day. Answer changed to reflect this.

Comment: Why are you doing the sum on the application side, when you can do it all mysql-server-side?

Comment: Mainly because I've only recently started using SQL Databases :D

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=(SELECT SUM(quantity) WHERE timestamp < some_timestamp AND category = (SELECT category FROM table WHERE ID='given_ID'))`

If I understood correctly, this would give you the line which ID is the sum of the quantity of all the lines that have an earlier timestamp and are in the same category as the provided ID.

I didn't test it, but something along those lines should work.